# Online tool for chess analysis: comment, add variations, insert diagrams, print

Tags: analysis, software, chessbase

Sometimes I like to analyze and annotate my own games and print them on paper. This would usually include commenting some moves, adding variations, inserting diagrams for certain positions, etc. I used to use [ChessBase](https://shop.chessbase.com/) software for Windows to do this.

Is there an online tool that can do such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [lichess.org](https://lichess.org/) and [Chess.com](http://www.chess.com/) allow you to upload, save, and annotate games like you mention. The first website provides this service as long as you register, which is free. The second website provides this only for premium users that have purchased a plan.