# Free best software for analyzing game in Windows 11 or Linux

Tags: software, linux, windows

I am not talking about Stockfish, Komodo or engine. I am talking about Software like Chess Arena. I was using the software, but I can't stay focused on it cause it doesn't have well defined GUI (doesn't have dark theme). It's not completely user-friendly. I wonder what Judit used [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LjprmtRCtU&t=924s). I have engine installed in my Desktop. So I want a software which can import the engine to analyze some particular positions.

Note : I don't want answer like chess.com, lichess.com or ChessBase (I just want a software which can import any kind of engine for analyzing games). (I am Linux and Windows 11 so the can be written for any of them)

Comment: Please check here
https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40290/what-free-programs-do-exist-to-comment-chess-games-for-windows-linux-and-mac/40291#40291

Comment: @WassimSaeed done!

Comment: It is ChessBase 14 in the video you linked.